# Is there a way for users to invite their friends via LinkedIn using iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, social-networking

I am done with login using linkedIn but I did a lot of goggling and did not find a way to invite friends via LinkedIn. If Somebody have done this then please give me a guidance or tutorial to get rid of this.

Any help will be appreciated..

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Once logged in, you should be able to invite people as friends using LinkedIn's own API. Check out the [documentation here](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/invitation-api). This will involve POSTing XML to the API as described on that page.

Note that there are some "usage guidelines" you'll need to follow, too (The user must be given a choice about whether to send the invitation, etc...)